# Wildfly support to solaris older version

Tags: java, wildfly

I am planning to migrate from JBOSS EAP to a Wildfly version which supports older versions of Java like 6 or 7.

I can't find a compatibility matrix with wild fly and java.

Also, does any version of wildfly supports solaris 5 ?

wildfly 8 , does it supports older java and Solaris versions.

can someone point me to the matrix where I can find wildfly compatibility and requirements.

Comment: What actual version of Solaris are you running (`uname -a`)?

Comment: @stdunbar SunOS 5.10

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a support matrix but I did find that there is a Java 8 JDK from OpenJDK that supports Solaris 10 and 11.  See [the AdoptOpenJDK release page](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot) to download it.  It is available for Sparc and x64.

With Java 8 you can run even Wildfly 20.  This is documented in the [Wildfly Requirements](https://docs.wildfly.org/20/Getting_Started_Guide.html#requirements):

> Java SE 8 or later. We recommend that you use the latest available
> update of the current long-term support Java release.

So you can be completely up to date with Wildfly and still on a LTS release of Java.

Comment: I wanted to check is any version of wildfly supports java 7 and solaris 5 series versions ?

Comment: The first Wildfly was version 8 and it required Java 8.  However, before it was Wildfly it was JBoss application server.  There are [downloads](https://jbossas.jboss.org/downloads/) for that going back 18 years.  They've not done a great job with documentation - it's not clear which version of Java is needed with which version.  But given that you're on an O/S released 15 years ago there has to be a version in there that will run with Java 7.  Just please tell me that your environment will not be published online :)